# PHP regular expressions exact data inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have some string like `Western Australia 223/5 (59.3 ov)`

I would like to split this string and extract the following informations with regular expressions

```
$team = 'Western Australia'
$runs = 223/5
$overs = 59.3
```

Issue is, format of the text is varying, it may any of the follwing

- Western Australia 223/5 (59.3 ov)
- Australia 223/5 (59.3 ov)
- KwaZulu-Natal Inland
- Sri Lanka v West Indies

Any help (like is it possible to have in a single regexp) will be appreciated..

Comment: In the latter two cases what is the expected output?

Comment: BoltClock beat me to it.  Yes...need more info!

Comment: I'm not sure what should be the output for latter twos!! :-) It can be the full string itself. I'm not concentrating on the meaning of the output, but trying not to get any error while dealing with regexps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match(
    '%^                 # start of string
    (?P<team>.*?)       # Any number of characters, as few as possible (--> team)
    (?:\s+              # Try to match the following group: whitespace plus...
     (?P<runs>\d+       # a string of the form number...
              (?:/\d+)? # optionally followed by /number
     )                  # (--> runs)
    )?                  # optionally
    (?:\s+              # Try to match the following group: whitespace plus...
     \(                 # (
     (?P<overs>[\d.]+)  # a number (optionally decimal) (--> overs)
     \s+ov\)            # followed by ov)
    )?                  # optionally
    \s*                 # optional whitespace at the end
    $                   # end of string
    %six', 
    $subject, $regs)) {
    $team = $regs['team'];
    $runs = $regs['runs'];
    $overs = $regs['overs'];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

You might need to catch an error if the matches `<runs>` and/or `<overs>` are not actually present in the string. I don't know much about PHP. (Don't know much biology...SCNR)

Comment: oops!!! expression failed for the latest score `Western Australia 324` http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/474039.html

Comment: OK, so the `/number` part is optional? No problem. Will edit.

Comment: `number/number` part is optional, possible cases can be `Western Australia`, `Western Australia 1/0`,`Western Australia 324/9`, `Western Australia 324`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using preg_match, you can use the following:

```
preg_match('/^([\w\s]+)\s*(\d+\/\d+)?\s*(\(\d+\.\d+ ov\))?$/', $input, $matches);
```

Then, you can inspect `$matches` to see which one of the options you are supossed to manage was found.

See [preg_match documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for more information.

Comment: Won't work. "Western Australia" is 2 words, not one. Also, it won't match the ()s around the ov bit.